# When I add a library, R file is removed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library, r.java-file, import-libraries

When I add a library, the R file is removed and I get the *"R cannot be resolved to a variable"* error.

This happens when I add the 
[`Android-ViewPagerIndicator`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) library by marking it as a library in its properties
and then add it to my project.

I have cleaned and rebuilt the project, but still the R file doesn't appear in the `/gen` folder

---

The library's `android-support-v4.jar` file was not the same as my project's, because its size is different by 200KB (600KB). I replaced the library's `android-support-v4.jar` with my project file; without this I get lot of errors!

Comment: When you have other problem/errors, your code does not compile properly and hence R would not be generated. It is probably some other  error . Open your "problem" view on IDE and see if you have any errors.

Comment: My IDE says that the two library should be same , mean android-support-v4.jar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your new library already have android-support-v4.jar in it, so now there are two. Try deleting the android-support-v4.jar from your libs folder.